# How do I get AnyDice to parse 1d2d4 the way I want it to?

Tags: anydice

The statement 1d2d4 is ambiguous.  I might mean (1d2)d4, which is what AnyDice guesses by default, but I also might mean 1d(2d4). It makes sense that the default behavior is as it is because Order of Operations is evaluated from left to right, but I can't seem to find *any* way to get AnyDice to let me input 1d(2d4).  Parentheses don't work, instead resulting in the statement being treated as just 2d4, which is weird, and if I write `2d(2d4)` the program seems to turn that into just 4d4.  You can see my trouble [here](http://anydice.com/program/aaba).

What can I do to get AnyDice to understand that I want to roll a single die of variable size (1d(2d4)) rather than a variable number of fixed-size dice ((1d2)d4)? And why don't parentheses work in the first place?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answers to your questions can be found in the documentation on arbitrary dice.

> Besides creating a die based on a single number, you can also create a die based on a sequence, for example d{1,2,4,4}. This allows you to create dice of any shape. It is also possible to explicitly create dice based on another die or collection of dice.

Essentially, anydice doesn't actually do anything with dice. To it, all dice are sequences. So when you give it 1d(2d4), it sees that as 1d{2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,8}. The "1d" then selects 1 number at random from that sequence, which is equivalent to rolling 2d4.

What you need is (as is usually the case with anydice) a function.

```
function: roll D:n {
result: dD
}
output [roll 2d4]
```

You can see the results [here](http://anydice.com/program/aabb). If you're wondering how this function works when all it does is use the same "d" as you did, it's because of the way anydice handles function parameters.

> **Expecting a number**
>
> If a sequence is provided, then the sequence will be summed. If a die is provided, then the function will be invoked for all numbers on the die – or the sums of a collection of dice – and the result will be a new die.

So by telling the function to expect a number, and giving it a die, it rolls the die and evaluates the function for all possible results individually.

Alternatively, you can do what anydice does, and just work out the sequence containing all the possible results - this approach works for anything you want to do, but generally involves a lot of tedious manual effort.

Comment: BTW, you can even define a more general wrapper function [like](http://anydice.com/program/abc0) `function: N:n x D:n { result: NdD }`, so that you can write e.g. `[1d6 x 2d4]` (or even `[[1x6] x [2x4]]`) and have it interpreted as "1d6 rolls of a die with 2d4 sides".

Comment: @IlmariKaronen That is *seriously* clever. I can't imagine what you would need it for, but it's a really beautiful bit of code.